# unable to connect sql server to AWS RDS ,error 258?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, rds

unabel to connect sql server to aws , any suggestions ?

remote connection is on , dbinstance and password is correct .

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Did you by any chance neglect to open in your AWS security group inbound port (i.e. 1433) to the IP from which the connection is made?  Open it to 0.0.0.0/0 if you elect to open to all (be cautioned about security implication though).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to edit your vpc security group options.

I had the same issue and did that and was resolved.